# Sanitizer Angularerror TS2339: Property 'bypassSecurityTrustUrl' does not exist on type 'Sanitizer'

Tags: angular

I have a problem with a sanitizer, I can not solve it.

```
ERROR in src/app/add-post/add-post.component.ts(24,42): error TS2339: Property 'bypassSecurityTrustUrl' does not exist on type 'Sanitizer'.
```

my code in this component

```
this.imagesUpload = this.sanitazer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(ev.target.files[i]));
      this.images.push(this.imagesUpload);

import { Component, OnInit, Sanitizer } from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: in the production version everything works, the problem appears during ng build

Comment: You should use [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer): `import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";`.

Comment: Thanks @ConnorsFan